# Is it haram to do freelancing work with Israel company

Tags: halal-haram, work

Assalamu alaikum.

I do freelancing work and get clients from around the world. Couple of days ago, I got a contract from an Israeli Web development company and they want to make the relationship longer. I am totally in a fix to decide whether I should go with it or not.

Can any one please guide me?

Comment: No work isn't like this at all. Its just a product based site.

Comment: So you freely accept “ clients from around the world,” but when you get Jew you suddenly backtrack? Is this anti Semitic?!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If there's one thing i avoid then giving advise. And I'm happy that this is hardly on topic here. So let me ask you: Is the job you are asked to do haram or related to haram things/deeds? Does your work help enemies of Islam to defeat Muslims or harm them? Is it any kind of propaganda against Islam or for any other belief?... If you answered any of these questions with yes then you should avoid it, if not then there's only a decision to make whether working with or for an Israeli company is considered as haram.

I think one can easily find evidences saying it isn't because of Verse of the Quran like [60:8](http://legacy.quran.com/60/8)!
However it would be better if you could do this job for Muslims or anybody who isn't considered as an enemy of Islam.

Here are evidences from the Prophet dealing with Jews:
From sahih [al-Bukhari](http://sunnah.com/bukhari/47/16):

> Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) rented the land of Khaibar to the Jews on the condition that they would work on it and cultivate it and take half of its yield.

From [sahih Muslim](http://sunnah.com/muslim/22/153):

> Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) bought some grain from a Jew on credit and gave him a coat-of- mail of his as a pledge.

See also [this fatwa](https://www.islamweb.net/ar/fatwa/238228) in Arabic on the topic and [this one](https://islamqa.info/en/20732) about boycotting products of enemies. And [this one](http://www.islamic-fatwa.com/fatwa/37332) in Arabic about working for Israelis as a translator.

Comment: Jews are not the enemy. This is anti Semitic. Muhammad gave many gifts to Jews throughout his life.

Comment: @Jonathan I think it is strange to call Arabs antisemitic (when they are Semite as well as the Jews are) its seems that this term only applies for anything were the supposed victim is Jewish and that itself is a big injustice. Israel is certainly not a harmless implantation in the region which wishes only good for its Arabic /Muslim neighbors (the issue has also a political and social impact). You may call this anti Zionist, but certainly not anti Semitic as I nowhere pretend that Jews are the enemy in fact I show that one cannot postmark believers of a certain faith as "the enemy" by default.

Comment: Let's pretend that that's true. Is it reasonable to assume all Israelis are bad? Since Arabs are semitic, the first ant-Semite was a Semite: Haman from the tribe of Amalek who attacked the Israelites when they exited Egypt. Be it as it may, Israel asked the Arabs six times for a two-state solution. Each time Palestine denied our offer and went to war. Each time they lost. Furthermore, the Palestinians refused to help draft Trump's "Deal of the Century." See, Israelis are not so bad after all.

Answer (score -1):

yes its haram, working with israel is haram, a muslim should not support anything that comes from israel in any way